# How to run a command when a set of parallel ones had success?

Tags: bash, time, command-line

I would like to run two commands in bash at the same time, wait for the success of both, and then run a third command. In addition, I would like to include this into a `time` command. Schematically:

```
time { { cmd_1 & cmd_2 & } && cmd 3; } &> time.log
```

If, for example, I run:

```
 time { { echo "hi" & sleep 5 & } && echo "ok"; } &> time.log
```

I get "ok" printed out immediately, without waiting for the success of the commands between curly brackets. Moreover, the `time.log` file contains the standard error and standard output of the two commands in brackets but the output of `time` is printed in the terminal only, not in the file.

I am sure I am missing something clear and easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
time (
    ( sleep 5; exit 1 ) & pid1=$!                      # process returns 1 and causes nok
    ( sleep 6; exit 0 ) & pid2=$!
    wait $pid1 && wait $pid2 && echo aok || echo nok   # wait for both and act accordingly
) 2> time_out                                          # time outputs to std_err
```

outputs

```
nok
```

as the first bg process returns 1.

Comment: I am having some trouble in using this command you suggested. It works when I use it as it is but it doesn't when I save the output of:
`( sleep 5; exit 1 ) & pid1=$!`
to a variable (X):
`X=$(sleep 5; exit 1 ) & pid1=$!`
Why?

Comment: I'd guess that once it's put in the background the output isn't ready and the background job blocks at the `wait` so `$X` never gets its value. Write the value to a file and read it from there later.

Answer (score 1):

`wait` returns when all child processes have finished, ignoring their exit status. `wait -n` returns when the next one finishes and returns its exit status.

Since you have two child processes you can chain two `wait -n`s.

```
time { echo "hi" & sleep 5 & wait -n && wait -n && echo "ok"; } &> time.log
```